# Parsing Underscore Seperated Key Value List

Tags: java, regex

We have filenames which contain a list of their identifiers and values, both seperated by underscores. At first this seemed easy to parse with a regex, but the problem is that both identifiers and values can contain *anything*. I do have access to a list of the identifiers though.
Here is an example:

Identifiers:

```
{PG, PGN, T, TN, Axis}
```

Filenames:

```
Measurement_2020-08-10 13.08.04.578_Batch counter_41.0_PGN_1338_TN_1337
Measurement_2020-08-10 13.05.15.065_Batch counter_39.0_PG_under_score_program_name_T_1337
Measurement_2020-08-10 13.05.15.065_Batch counter_39.0_Axis_unsolvable_PG_T_bla
```

Expected results:

```
{[PGN,1338],[T,1337]}
{[PG,under_score_program_name],[T,1337]}
ambiguous. two possible solutions {[Axis,unsolvable_PG],[T,bla]} OR {[Axis,unsolvable],[PG,T_bla]}
```

As you can see i constructed some of these for testing certain problematic values. Especially the last one where an identifier is actually used as part of a value...

Obviously there must be a way to solve this, since i can look at it and figure it out quite quickly, but i just can't come up with a way to parse this correctly.

Added the regex tag because it could be possible to solve this with one.

Thank you in advance for suggestions :)

Comment: If you can identify this pretty quickly, you have to explain (in the question, please, not the comments) exactly what the rules are. Why "Axis,unsolvable_PG" and not "Axis_unsolvable,PG"? Do you have a list of the identifiers in advance?

Comment: I do, i said so in my post. And i can identify it pretty quickly because i know that it always has to be KEY_VALUE_KEY2_VALUE2 and so on.

Comment: Still, I don't see how you know it's "[Axis,unsolvable_PG],[T,bla]" rather than "[Axis,unsolvable],[PG,T_bla]".

Comment: Good point. I don't actually. I guess some cases *will* be unsolvable. I guess in that case both solutions are acceptable.

Comment: My suggestion would be, if at all possible, to encode the file names differently to prevent this. Use plus signs, or if not possible, three consecutive underscores.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are absolutely correct and i actually intend to do that going forward. But the problem is that this has to deal with legacy files also.

Answer (score 0):

plain old StringTokenizer...

```
public class FilenameParser {

    private Set<String> keywords;

    public FilenameParser(Set<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    public Map<String,String> parse(String filename) {
        Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(filename, "_");
        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            nextToken(token, tokenizer, results);
        }

        return results;
    }

    private void nextToken(String token, StringTokenizer tokenizer, Map<String, String> results) {
        if(keywords.contains(token)) {
            boolean keywordFound = false;
            String key = token;
            List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() && ! keywordFound ) {
                token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                if(keywords.contains(token)) {
                    keywordFound = true;

                    nextToken(token, tokenizer, results);

                } else {
                    value.add(token);
                }
            }

            results.put(key, value.stream().reduce((left, right) -> {
                return left + "_" + right;
            }).orElse(""));
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>();
        keywords.addAll(Arrays.asList("PG", "PGN", "T", "TN", "Axis"));

        FilenameParser parser = new FilenameParser(keywords);

        Map<String,String> result = parser.parse("Measurement_2020-08-10 13.05.15.065_Batch counter_39.0_Axis_unsolvable_PG_T_bla");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Result: {T=bla, PG=, Axis=unsolvable}

Comment: The OP said that the result should be `{T=bla,Axis=unsolvable_PG}` for this file.

Comment: code can be edited to match this result, just return empty key from nextToken and add it to the previous values...  but it looks ambigous. Using the pattern key_value_key2_value2 as mentioned in the comments PG is a key an there's no value for it

Comment: Well, that's exactly the OP's problem - keys and values may contain underscores.